# popup with resizing controls

Tags: html, popup

I want to call a popup window where i lock the window size to maximum size possible and don't allow size/ aspect ratio to be changed subsequently. This saves overhead of doing relative sizing and positioning multiple times.

When I do use jscript, i find code that works for IE but not chrome and vice versa (haven't checked on any other browser). Is it possible to have single common solution for all browsers

function newPopup(url) { popupWindow= window.open(  url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=1200,left=1,top=1,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}

popup open

The script line is getting truncated from message...

Answer (score 0):

No, because other browsers are designed to be user-friendly, which, for example, means that the user can resize a window whenever he wants to.